# VS code python formatter not working(autopep8, black, yapf)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, format, autopep8

I am using VS Code 1.60 on macbook pro, Big Sur 11.4 with python 3.9.7.

I have installed Python(Microsoft) extension for formatting. Before installing it, syntax errors were not highlighted. After installation, highlights with red lines. But, formatting is not working both shortcut key(command-shift-f for mac) and right-click format.

When trying to format a file, a short blinking message is shown at the bottom of vs code, "formatting with autopep8", without real formatting.

I haven't touched anything in settings.json both user and workspace.
settings.json of workspace has nothing, and the only sentence in settings.json of user directory is ""python.formatting.provider": "autopep8""

I have struggled to make the formatter work, but in veil, tried other formatters but not working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In addtion, at the bottom of vs code shows the python version is 3.9.7 with path of usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: I had a similar issue and have posted it into their GitHub issue, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17425 which indicates that A/B experiments of Python extension may cause it. I tried to disable it and no hang happens !!